# Mocking an async function to return same response more than once during test

Tags: .net, moq, xunit

I am trying to write a unit test case using xUnit.
I want to test a function (F1) which internally calls 2 functions (F2 & F3) which further calls the same function (F4).

F4 is an async function which I am mocking using Moq. I need to return true from F4 both times its called internally.

```
cP.Setup(x => x.F4()).ReturnsAsync(true);
```

I checked with Verify() method, its being called only once.

What can be the solution here...

Comment: From a first glance your mock setup looks okay. Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I think your moq class is not static, thus not sharing this setup between tests. Still I can't say that for sure until I see more code.